# Touches outside of UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  NSLog(@"The tag %i",touch.view.tag);
  if( [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] ) {
    for( UIView *checkview in [self.view subviews] ) {
      if( [checkview tag] == 1 ) {
        infoIsVisibile = NO;
        [info removeFromSuperview];                         
      }
    }
  }
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Can someone help me, this will only detect touches inside the subview and not the mainview.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail? For example, is this in a custom view? Where is that view? How was it attached?... Also, you shouldn't mutate an array while you're iterating it (here you remove a subview while iterating the subviews array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook up a UIGestureRecognizer to the view you're interested in.

(In general, gesture recognizers are a much more robust mechanism for detecting touches in arbitrary views, and they will play nicely with views like UIWebViews and UIScrollViews that tend to eat conventional touch events.)

Here's a snippet:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleDoubleTap:)];
    singleFingerDTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.theView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];
    [singleFingerDTap release];
```

(This code is from the linked docs below -- note that self.theView is presumably some random view stored as a member of the current object.)

You'll be happily surprised (or shocked) at how much gesture recognizers simplify your code and reduce weirdness.

Here's a link to Apple's docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Comment: What i am trying to do, is when i click on a button on my UIViewController, a subview pops up and when i want to close the UIView i touch outside the UIView, i have added the gestures code, but it closes the UIView no matter what i touch